# How can i list properties of child objects in the WPF Tookit PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

I am working with the propertyGrid from Xceed WPF tookit property grid.

When I bind an object to the grid, it lists the nested classes within it using the ToString() method and is read-only. I would like it to also list the properties within these nested classes. Does property grid support this? Is there a better library for this?

e.g.

```
Class Parameters {
    public int number {get;set;}
    Public CustomVector vector1 {get; set;} 
    Public CustomVector vector2 {get; set;}
}

Class CustomerVector {
    public double a {get; set;}
    public double b {get; set;}
    public double c {get; set;}
    public double d {get; set;}
}
```

In this case it would just list 3 elements, returning the ToString() for vector1 and vector2. I would like it to let me edit a,b,c,d of both vectors.

Comment: I would suggest using data templates instead of property grid. I think that is more maintainable with changes. You have enough control to do specific changes for specific types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding Parameters}">
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
        <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="number" />
        <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="vector1"
                                 IsExpandable="true" />
        <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="vector2"
                                 IsExpandable="true" />
    </xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

`IsExpandable="true"` enables the property editor to expand to sub properties

also you can customize the display value of root (vector1, vector2) by overriding `ToString()` method in `CustomerVector` class

eg

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", a, b, c, d);
    }
```

result

[image: result]

Comment: Has to be said that these definitions can be done pre-emptively. Meaning even if you don't have that property in a listing for a particular type, that's completely fine - once you add some other object, `IsExpandable` will kick in. Convenient.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the **[ExpandableObject]** attribute on the nested objects, but this means polluting the class with WPF/presentation attributes (you could wrap the data class in a UI model class to keep things separate).

If we simply want all nested objects in unknown object types to be exapandable we can do something like this:

```
private void PropGrid_PreparePropertyItem(object sender, PropertyItemEventArgs e)
{
    var prop = e.Item as PropertyItem;
    if (prop != null)
    {
        prop.IsExpandable = prop.PropertyType.IsClass;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find an option to just get it to do this by default for any object.